# why in react version 16.8.6 css that required in component affects in an other components also all css apear in header Instead of chunk.css

Tags: css, reactjs, single-page-application

i created two css file in my react app login.css and main.css then require login.css in login.jsx and main.css require for an other files but css writed in login.css affect to an other components. also  With a little focus i find all css file loaded in header generally for all component

Answer (score 0):

CSS imported inside a component it's **not scoped by its own.** If your CSS have a general rule it will influence the whole page.

Importing CSS inside a component is great because you will automatically remove it if you delete the component and, in case your component is loaded asynchronously with a chunk it *can* be imported later. That's depends on webpack settings.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but  when i inspect element in browser  all css file showing in header(inline)

Comment: for example when i require('./NavMenu.css') in NavMenu.js css run for all component